# How long does it take to place an item in a Bag of Holding or Portable Hole?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, actions

The descriptions of a Bag of Holding and Portable Hole are very specific about how long it takes to retrieve items from them, but do not have any indication of how long it takes to place an item in them. In contrast, the  description of the Handy Haversack specifically says that placing an object in it requires your object interaction.

So, if my character wanted to place an object in a Bag of Holding or Portable Hole in the middle of combat, would it require an action, object interaction, or something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Considering a bag of holding is essentially just a messenger bag with a significant amount of storage, it's reasonable that the "free action" or environment action would be used to stow an item into it, much the same as retrieving an item from it.

As for the portable hole, by itself it requires an action to unfurl the entire thing **onto a flat surface** to grant access to the contents. At the point it is open, anyone would be able to use a "free action" or environment action to toss something into the hole.

Comment: The term you are looking for is "interaction" or "object interaction". there is no free actions or environmental actions in 5e.