# How much time does putting an item inside a Bag of Holding take when you are fighting?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items, actions

In the ***Bag of Holding's*** (Dungeon Master's Guide pag. 248) description it is stated:

> Retrieving a specific item from a bag of holding is a *move action* — unless the bag contains more than an ordinary backpack would hold, in which case retrieving a specific item is a *full-round action*.

I am wondering how much time is required to put an item inside the bag while you are engaged in a **combat encounter**. Should it be considered as a *move action* as well? Should it be a *free action* if the item is small enough?

I have found this question that is almost the same as this one: [How long does it take to place an item in a Bag of Holding or Portable Hole?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/147045/how-long-does-it-take-to-place-an-item-in-a-bag-of-holding-or-portable-hole)

The only thing that has not been made clear is: does the **item's size** influence the time I must spend to put something inside the bag?

Ex: Does a rod take more time than a ring? What about an halberd and a sword?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It’s a move action:

> #### Manipulate an Item
>
> In most cases, moving or manipulating an item is a move action.
>
> This includes retrieving or **putting away a stored item**, picking up an item, moving a heavy object, and opening a door. Examples of this kind of action, along with whether they incur an attack of opportunity, are given in Table: Move Actions.

<sup>([Actions in Combat → Move Actions](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#manipulateanItem), **emphasis** mine)</sup>

> #### MOVE ACTION
>
> A move action allows you to [...] stow a weapon or other item

<sup>(*Rules Compendium* pg. 7)</sup>

Nothing in the description of *bag of holding* suggests that stowing an item would take a different amount of time, and no rule mentions item size having any effect.

Less clear is whether or not this process provokes an attack of opportunity—it almost certainly does, since everything **else** about manipulating an item that **isn’t** “draw a weapon from a sheath” does—including sheathing a weapon again. But neither the core rules nor *Rules Compendium* comes out and says this.

The other issue to keep in mind is that the move action to stow an item in a *bag of holding* requires that the *bag* itself be accessible. The rules for this are very vague, and it’s basically up to the DM—you’re definitely OK if the bag is in your hand, or say, on your belt. Conversely, if your *bag of holding* is inside another container, that will definitely require more to retrieve the *bag* before you can stow anything in it. If it’s on your back, though, that’s much less clear—you may need to spend a move action pulling it off your back first, and then spend another move action actually putting your item into it. That call is just up to the DM in each case.

Comment: Although I've always played that it does, what I couldn't find is if stowing an item provokes attacks of opportunity like sheathing a weapon does. Could this answer address that, too, or should that be it's own question?

Comment: @HeyICanChan So far as I know, there’s no rule that says explicitly—pretty much every other type of item manipulation that isn’t drawing a weapon does, so I assume this would too, but since this question didn’t ask it seems weird to point out that I don’t know, and in a question that did ask I wouldn’t have much to say beyond “here’s all the places the rule isn’t, here’s why it probably does,” which isn’t really satisfying or telling you anything you don’t already know.

Comment: Fair enough. Whether or not it provokes just seemed like the kind of value-add that you're fond of (and my not being able to find anything about it was why I didn't answer this question). That said, is it worth addressing how the *bag* itself is being toted? That is, must the *bag* itself be retrieved prior to stowing an item within?

Comment: @HeyICanChan It would be, *if* I had an answer for it, but I don’t. As for how the *bag* is stored, yes, that is relevant. I could add something about that... in the morning ;). Good night.

Comment: I'm also interested in that last question. I.e. can one put an item into pickaback backpack?

Comment: @annoyingimp On Move Action says that "you could… pick up an item and stow it in your backpack (two move actions)" (*PH* 138), but I honestly don't know if that sentence's author assumes a *currently worn* backpack. I mean, it *should* be on your back—hence the name—, but it could also be dropped on the ground, in your hand, or even in your lair in a far-off land. (Needless to say, that last is unlikely.) If that example were a belt pouch I think we'd automatically assume that it's worn, but reality tells us it's darn awkward to stow something in a backpack that's on your back.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing in the [rules](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#tableMoveActions) states the size of an item affects the (normally, *move*) action to put an item away, so typically, the size doesn't affect it.  Putting items into a bag is never a free action - you have to look down, grab the bag from where you've got it, open it, put the item in, close it back up tight, and put it back where you keep it - I'm surprised it's just a move action, honestly.

Of course, an individual DM may change the storage time for items that can only be put away like because you have a physics-defying bag.  If they want to make it a standard or full-round action to put away a 10-ft pole or a ladder, that's reasonable, but by default rules, it's just a move action.